# Error when Querying Join Tables using JPQL

Tags: jpa, jpql

I am trying to query an entity called Section which has a many to many relation with an entity called students. see the section entity below

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="Sections")
public class Section implements Serializable  {

@Id
private int crn;
private String sectionCode;
private String courseCode;
private String semester;
private int instructorId;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="instructorId", referencedColumnName="id" , 
insertable=false,     updatable=false)
private Instructor instructor;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="courseCode", referencedColumnName="courseCode" ,
 insertable=false,  updatable=false)
private Course course;
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="Student_Section",
  joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Enrolledcrn", referencedColumnName="crn"),
  inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id"))
private List<Student> students;
```

one section has many students and many students can be in the same section. I created a join table called Student_Section which tells which students enrolled in which section here is a snapshot of this table

```
ENROLLEDCRN ID
----------- --
   13151     6
   13151     7
   13151     8
   13151     9
   13151    10
   13151    11
```

The question is : I am trying to get a list of sections taken in a specific semester for a specific student. I tried the following query:

```java
List<Section> student_Sections= em.createQuery("select s from Section s inner join s.students e "
            + "where e.id = :userID AND s.semester = :semester AND e.ENROLLEDCRN = :s.crn").
            setParameter("semester", semester)
            .setParameter("userID", userID)
            .getResultList();
```

But this error appears ! 
(The named input parameter ''{0}'' is not following the rules for a Java identifier.) 
Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

here his some part of the table Section after creation :

```
CRN    COURSECODE INSTRUCTORID SECTIONCODE SEMESTER
-----  ---------- ------------ ----------- -----------

14251   CMPS251              2    L51      Spring 2014
13251   CMPE263              3    L51      Fall 2013
```

Comment: Can you try with `e.ENROLLEDCRN = s.crn`, removed `:`

Comment: I tried and I got this error 
"The state field path 'e.ENROLLEDCRN' cannot be resolved to a valid type." 

Did you understand well my question, or you need more clarification ? @NayanWadekar

Comment: Note that when I run the query without 'e.ENROLLEDCRN = :s.crn' it works and return fir my all sections in the given semester which is wrong as I want the sections in specific semester for a specific user who is enrolled in these section which we can know from the ENROLLEDCRN column in the many to many join relation @NayanWadekar

Comment: I think issue is with this - `e.ENROLLEDCRN`, can you try with exact column name. I see this `Enrolledcrn` in given code. Note that some system(Linux)/DB, column names are case sensitive.

Comment: Yes, I tried this issue but this error appears 
The named input parameter ''{0}'' is not following the rules for a Java identifier.

Comment: I added some part of the Section table after creation to my question @NayanWadekar

Comment: Try once with `select s from Section s inner join s.students e where e.id = :studentId AND s.semester = :semester AND e.Enrolledcrn = s.crn` with parameters as `setParameter("studentId", userID).setParameter("semester", semester)`